# How do I replace all hashtags in a contenteditable div with a hyperlink while ignoring previously replaced hashtags?

Tags: jquery, html, replace, hashtag

I am building a hashtag converter function. Every time the user clicks on enter or on space I need to check if the user has hashtags in his text. I have used previous answers with this regex:

**HTML**

```
<div class="post-input-field" contenteditable="true">My favourite dish is <a href=#>#sushi</a>#but I also like #pizza. </div>
```

**JQuery**

```
/**
* Trigger when someone releases a key on the field where you can post remarks, posts or reactions
*/
$(document).on("keyup", ".post-input-field", function (event) {

   // if the user has pressed the spacebar (32) or the enter key (13)
   if (event.keyCode === 32 || event.keyCode === 13) {
      currentCommentText = currentCommentText.replace(/#(\w+)/g, "<a class='hashtag' href=" + url + " target='_blank'>$&</a>&nbsp;").replace("<br>", ""); //replace hashtags with a link

      textField.html(currentCommentText);
   }
});
```

This works fine if the user writes every unique hashtag once. However, when the user types the same hashtag twice, it adds the link in front of the previously fetched hashtag too.

[image]
As you can see there are several spaces behind #sushi and #pizza. If I zoom in and check why this happens:
[image]

You can see that the regex is not really doing it's job. I have heard that using regex to replace html is not very optimal. Is there a way I can check hashtags and only replace the hashtags that have not been converted in the text yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex looks for all hashtags that are not already wrapped in a hyperlink. It also creates two groups that we can use to form the link of the hashtag.
https://regex101.com/r/EUNySg/13

```
/(?!\s*#\w+\s*<\/a>)(#(\w+))/g
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).on("keyup", ".post-input-field", function (event) {
   if (event.keyCode === 32 || event.keyCode === 13) {
      let html = $(this).html();
      html = html.replace( /(?!\s*#\w+\s*<\/a>)(#(\w+))/g, "<a class='hashtag' href='https://google.com/$1'>$2</a>&nbsp;").replace("<br>", ""); 
      $(this).html(html);
   }
});
```

Below you can see that all #hashtag get highlighed, but the #notahashtag do not get highlighted.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## Option 1:

Strip the HTML from the string before doing the replacement on it again. Just drop the HTML in a blank div and then get the text out of it.

```js
$(document).on("keyup", ".post-input-field", function (event) {
   if (event.keyCode === 32 || event.keyCode === 13) {
      var val = $(this).val();
      // strip html from val
      val = $('<div>').html(val).text();
      val = val.replace(/#(\w+)/g, "<a class='hashtag' href=#>$&</a>&nbsp;").replace("<br>", ""); 
      $(this).val(val);
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="post-input-field" contenteditable="true"></textarea>
```

## Option 2:

Start your pattern with `(^|\s)`, which will only match hashtags at the begining of the line (`^`) or hashtags that follow some whitespace (`\s`) - This will cause it to ignore hashtags that are already in an anchor tag. You'll then have to replace the replacement string to include the second matched group (`$2`).

```js
$(document).on("keyup", ".post-input-field", function (event) {
   if (event.keyCode === 32 || event.keyCode === 13) {
      var val = $(this).val();
      val = val.replace(/(^|\s)(#\w+)/g, " <a href=#>$2</a>").replace("<br>", ""); 
      $(this).val(val);
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="post-input-field" contenteditable="true"></textarea>
```

Comment: This does not work for this string: "<a href=$>#hashtag</a>#hashtag" the last #hashtag should also match

Comment: @IT-Girl - option one works fine for that use case. that's why i made it option one.

Comment: Option 1 does not work , because it will strip ALL html that is in the text. Including previous hashtags that were added. This is a function that is fired more than once. It gets fired every time the user presses enter or space. Besides my element is a contenteditable div that contains more html than just the hashtags.

Comment: @IT-Girl - that is information that should have been included in the question. i'm a volunteer, the only pay i get from spending my time on your problem is your votes. normally i'd be happy to revise my answer but there is really no incentive for me to continue trying to help you after you've demonstrated that you're going to hold my upvote hostage until i write the exact code that you want. s.o. is not a free code writing service. if you would like to hire me to help with your project my contact info is on my profile. good luck.

Comment: I did not hold your upvote hostage. I am just saying that your code did not help my problem, thats why I removed my initial upvote. I have found the solution and will add it to my question, so you can see why it did not work.

Comment: I did not want to offend you. I build a better regex that will work for all html

Comment: @IT-Girl - you removed not only the upvote, but you un-accepted the answer after having previously said that it works. that's what i meant by "holding it hostage." i'm not offended, just a little disappointed. in any case. i'm glad you found something that works for you.

Comment: I did remove the accepted answer, because in the end it did not work when we tested the regex on our acceptance environment. Stackoverflow allows us to do this, so it's not really done on purpose. I do not want it to stay as the accepted answer as it did not work. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: I  did not remove the upvote, because I wanted you to write the correct code for me. Sorry for the misunderstanding. I appreciate the work you have done to find the fix, and I thank you for it. I apoligize if I might've given you a different impression and I wish you also good luck with your volunteer work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198245/discussion-between-it-girl-and-i-wrestled-a-bear-once).